# Losing stairs in other meshes when joining objects

Tags: mesh

I am a Newbie to Blender.

My dilemma is that l have four sets of stairs as individual objects in a scene, with various other objects and when l combine all the objects into one scene/object, the stairs are integrated into the other meshes and disappear.

Is there any way of combining the objects without losing the stairs?

Screenshots of before and after joining objects. I have applied textures using Cycles render before joining the objects, is that the problem?

[image: before joining]

[image: before joining]

Comment: Do you mean losing them in the Outliner, as separate objects, or do you mean they disappear, visually?

Comment: do you mean you join objects with ctrl J? like Caleb I think you must apply some modifiers to your object before joining it, perhaps an Array... otherwise it will not be taken into account

Comment: selecting them with b drawing box around objects and then join from tools menu.. yes the stairs are from and array, is that the cause?

Comment: would like to add, that the help from everyone is very much appreciated.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They shouldn't join meshes. One object can have multiple parts. Are you in cycles or render mode? I think your problem is most likely an unapplied subdivision modifier on one object and when you join the others this affects them. To fix this apply your modifiers before you join. 
Hope this has helped.

Just a note for next time: please post either the .blend file or screenshots of the problem. That makes it a lot easier to see what's wrong.